# C++ reading from file using std

Tags: c++, std

I'm trying to read from file, and I know how to do that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::string filename = "data.txt";
    std::ifstream from(filename);
    std::vector<int> values((std::istream_iterator<int>(from)), std::istream_iterator<int>());
    return 0;
}
```

My question is how to do the same thing in functional way:

```
int fromfile(std::string filename, std::vector<int> &values)
{
... 
    return 0;
}
```

The native way doesn't work:

```
int fromfile(std::string filename, std::vector<int> &values)
{
    std::ifstream from(filename);
    values((std::istream_iterator<int>(from)), std::istream_iterator<int>());
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your functional way doesn't work because you're trying to use a constructor on an already constructed object - so it looks like you're trying to invoke `operator()` on your `vector`, which does not exist. However, `vector` does have an [`assign`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign) member function that does the same thing, without the need for extra parens:

```
int fromfile(std::string filename, std::vector<int> &values)
{
    std::ifstream from(filename);
    values.assign(std::istream_iterator<int>(from), std::istream_iterator<int>());
    return 0;
}
```

Although the real functional way probably looks like this (C++11) - use the function to *return* the `vector`:

```
std::vector<int> fromfile(std::string filename)
{
    std::ifstream from(filename)
    return {std::istream_iterator<int>(from), std::istream_iterator<int>{}};
}
```

As is having an `int` return is somewhat useless if you just have `return 0`...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Barry, but as I know returning the vector is the copy-process, and if it contains more than 10^6 elements it might be expensive. The idea of returning an integer was to avoid copy-procedure.

Comment: @Maxim.K. True if you were copying. But we're not. If you just need the values (e.g. `vector<int> v = fromfile("something");`, that will not invoke a copy - see *return value optimization*. Also, even if you vector was already constructed (e.g. `v = fromfile("something_else");`), that would still only invoke a move.

Comment: @Barry The move will only happen in C++11 or above.  in C++98/03 it would be a copy.

Comment: @NathanOliver It's 2015. I'm assuming C++11 by default unless explicitly stated otherwise. RVO still existed in C++03 as well.

Comment: @Barry Yes RVO existed but if `v` already exist then `v = fromfile("something_else");` would need to copy.

Answer (score 1):

Notwithstanding the answer Barry has given to you, the other way to do this with algorithm is to call std::copy:

```
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(from), std::istream_iterator<int>(),
          std::back_inserter(values));
```